# Django displaying data from database in template

Tags: python, django

I'm having some trouble displaying data from my database on the template in django

model:

```
class CityInfo (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    landmark_type = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)

    business = 'Business'
    student = 'Student'
    tourist = 'Tourist'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

relevant view:

```
def itemget(request):
    data=CityInfo.objects.all()
    return render(request,'CityApp/infopage.html', {'data': data})
```

relevant url:

```
url(r'itemget/$',views.itemget,{'template_name': 'CityApp/info_page.html'},name='itemget'),
```

infopage.html:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in data %}
    <li>      
        <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
     </li>
    {% endfor %}
<ul>
```

The above html results in a blank list and I have no idea why.

Comment: Go to the django shell. Import your model. Run your queryset and try to manipulate the data there to make sure your not having issues with your model.

Comment: There is a discrepancy in your naming. In urls it is named info_page.html in view it is named infopage.html

Comment: @noes1s Can manipulate data fine through the shell and same issue after fixing the naming discrepancy

Comment: good catch @noes1s your template seems to be named wrong. Check you dont have the data being spit out on a differently named template. Code looks fine for python3

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `views.py` to the following:

```
def itemget(request):
    data = CityInfo.objects.all()
    context={
      'data': data
    }
    return render(request, "CityApp/infopage.html", context)
```

Comment: Please update your question with views.py and urls.py

Comment: The relevant view was always there but added the relevant url

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s"  %  self.name
```

I'm not sure because I'm on my old smartphone.

Otherwise, your `def __str__`  is well indented in your class  ?

Are you using Python 2 or Python 3  ?  `str` if for Python 3. Else you have to use `__unicode__`

**EDIT :**

From you urls.py file, you have :

```
url(r'itemget/$',views.itemget,{'template_name': 'CityApp/info_page.html'},name='itemget'),
```

Remove your `template_name part` which is already in your view and don't forget to add `^` before `itemget`

```
url(r'^itemget/$',views.itemget ,name='itemget'),
```